# Sum Digit Lines VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to calculate the sum of the Digit on each line separately.

Textbox1.Text =

```
13
7
47
79
15
```

Output: Expected:

```
4 7 11 16 16
```

Code:

```
    Dim lstsum = TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines(0).Split(",")
    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
    For Each sum In lstsum
        sb.AppendLine(sum.ToString)
    Next
    TxtMReadOnlyX.Text = sb.ToString
```

Comment: Please check input and question details. Your code is not matching with the details provided at all.

Comment: I think you mean 6, not 16 for the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Ok, so here's a way, using the fact that you can cast a char to an int and it is the ASCII value of the char. Char "1"c as an int is 49, so to turn a "1"c into an int and subtract 48, we get 1 as an int</strike>

Edit: to achieve the c#-esque conversion of char->int we could use Asc to convert "1"c to 49 and subtract 48, or we can use Val to interpret "1"c as 1. This code uses the Val route:

```
For Each line as String in textbox.Lines
  Dim cs as Char() = line.ToCharArray()
  Dim sum as Integer = 0

  For Each c As Char in cs
    sum = sum + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val(c)
  Next c

  OutputTextBox.AppendText(sum.ToString() + " ")

Next line
```

Comment: sum = sum + DirectCast(c as Integer) - 48 - error. syntax error

Comment: What won't compile?

Comment: And the error message is "DirectCast expects two arguments separated by a comma" so it was a rather trivial typo (confusion from SQL's cast route) that the compiler advice is helpful in fixing. The error then becomes an advisory that VB doesn't convert char  to Integer and suggests to use Asc or Val. All in this was a very minor mistake, the likes of which I do make occasionally and I may be forever curious why a) the OPs don't try to fix them and b) the bystanding professionals all pile on commenting about it rather than just hitting the edit button..

Answer (score 1):

Here is some LINQ

```vb
String.Join(" ", TextBox1.Lines.Select(Function(l) l.Sum(Function(c) Integer.Parse(c))))
```

Explanation:

1. `TextBox1.Lines` gets the lines
2. `.Select(Function(l) l` each line string
3. `.Sum(Function(c)` enumerating the string returns chars, passed into Sum
4. `Integer.Parse(c)` the chars are converted into integers before being summed
5. `.Select` revisiting this, the result is now IEnumerable(Of Integer) because of Sum
6. `String.Join(" ", IEnumerable(Of Integer))` being passed into String.Join, separated by a space